# Telerik RadGridView.ExportToXlsx - format cells as number

Tags: excel, wpf, radgridview

I need the Excel export of a `RadGridView` to have a cell format of "Number" in Excel, with a format style of "{0:#,##0.00}".

I achieved that using .Export, handling the `ElementExporting` event:

```
grid.ElementExporting += Grid_ElementExporting;
grid.Export(stream, new GridViewExportOptions()
{
  Format = ExportFormat.ExcelML,
  ShowColumnHeaders = true,
  ShowColumnFooters = true
});

private void Grid_ElementExporting(object sender, GridViewElementExportingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Element == ExportElement.Cell)
            {
                var column = e.Context as GridViewDataColumn;
                if (column?.DataType?.Name == "Decimal")
                {
                    e.Value = string.Format(@"{0:#,##0.00}", e.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

However I receive an error on opening in Excel "*The file format and extension of X don't match."*, despite it definitely being of .xls extension.  I can click past that and it loads correctly.

Reading up on it more, it sounds like I should update to use the .ExportToXlsx instead, and getting the files in .xlsx would be a perk anyway.

I change `.Export` to `.ExportToXlxs`, and the `ElementExporting` to `ElementExportingToDocument`, and the formatting is working, but all cells are back to being of format "General" in Excel, whereas I need them as "Number".

There's documentation on applying visual styles:
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/export/how-to/style-exported-documents

But not to change the underlying format that I can find.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try to create a `CellValueFormat` as explained in [the official docs](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radgridview/export/how-to/export-datetime)?

Comment: I had, but it looks like I had been mis-using it.  I had tried "Format = CellValueFormat.", and then seen that the only option was GeneralFormat.  I will experiment with creating one, thanks.

Comment: The `CellValueFormat` class is defined in `Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.dll`. You need to reference this assembly.

Comment: Many thanks, that's done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `CellValueFormat` as explained in [the official docs](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radgridview/export/how-to/export-datetime).

The `CellValueFormat` class is defined in `Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.dll` so you need to reference this assembly